# Unable to pass array variable in email with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Here is my code

```
$success = $this->user_model->get_user($user_id);
//$success variable contains some array values 
if($success){
    $this->email->from('username@domain.com'));
    $this->email->to($success->email);
    $this->email->subject('New user registration and update');
    $message = $this->load->view('email/view_adduser', $success, true);
    $this->email->message($message);
    $this->email->send();
 }
```

Email is sucessfully sent, but data aren't displaying there.
And here is my email view template(email/view_adduser.php)

```
<h2>Hello Sir/Madam</h2><br />
<p>Your Login credientials are provided below</p><br />
<p>Please <a href="<?php echo base_url().'admin'; ?>" >Login</a> 
To access your account </p><br />
<p>Username & Password : - <?php echo $success->username;?></p><br />
```

Here username is not displaying in the email.
Anybody have any idea???
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you positive the array contains the proper data? Maybe try using `var_dump($success)` and see what is displayed.

Comment: You should be using $username in the view as CI converts it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the data in your view as `$success->username` then you should wrap the user object in an array when passing it to the view like this:

```
$message = $this->load->view('email/view_adduser', array('success' => $success), true);
```

Otherwise you can access the data directly without the `$success` object, i.e: `$username` instead of `$success->username`